# How to use Standard Library function in include file

Tags: c++

func.h

```
void in(){}
```

func.cpp

```
void in(){  
printf("HelloWorld");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "iostream"
#include "func.h"
int main(){
    in();
}
```

`error C3861: 'printf': identifier not found`

Help me to solve this problem, thanks

Comment: What's the `/#include` notation about?

Comment: because i cann't type #include so i type /#include instead, but it is not the problem

Comment: for the error you get (void in(){}) remove the {} in the .h file :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Note that people expect you to provide syntactically correct code most of the time, so posting code with notations like `/#include "iostream"` makes you look a little silly.  You should be using the angle brackets notation `#include <iostream>` (because that's how the standard writes it), though the double quotes do work.

Answer (score 2):

Your source file `func.cpp` should `#include <cstdio>` or perhaps `#include <stdio.h>` to declare `printf()` before you use it. With `<cstdio>`, you get to use namespace `std`, so you might write `using namespace::std;` after the `#include` line, or you might use `std::` as a prefix to the function name.

You also need `#include "func.h"` in `func.cpp`.

#### `func.cpp` — Option 1

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "func.h"

void in()
{  
    std::printf("HelloWorld");
}
```

#### `func.cpp` — Option 2

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "func.h"
using namespace std;

void in()
{  
    printf("HelloWorld");
}
```

#### `func.cpp` — Option 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

void in()
{  
    printf("HelloWorld");
}
```

Option 1 is probably the preferred one.

#### func.h

Also, the header should declare the function, not define it, unless you really want an empty function body for the function — in which case you don't need the source file `func.cpp` at all.

```
void in();
```

Usually, a header should be protected against multiple inclusion.  This time, it won't hurt, but it is a good idea to learn good habits:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNC_H_INCLUDED

void in();

#endif /* FUNC_H_INCLUDED */
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2084: function 'void in(void)' already has a body, sr i'm not good at english

Comment: please don't recommend `using namespace std;` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: See the update about the header.